# Time Series: Generic Model for Multiple Time Series

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, panel-data

I currently have a sample of 75 participants that were tracked for a period of 160 days.

I want to build a multivariate time series model to predict the number of hours they will exercise on days 150-160 using the data from 1-149. The two predictors I have are (1) the number of hours they exercised per day and (2) high temperature for the day.

Do I need to build a separate model for each person? Is there a proper way to combine the data to be able to build one consensus model for forecasting?

Thank you. I am very new to time series data and forecasting. I hope my objective is clear.

Comment: Sounds like you have a good panel data set on your hand. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data

Comment: Is your requirement to predict for each person or to predict "expected number of hours a *randomly chosen individual* would exercise on a given day"?

Comment: Predict for each person. That is why I do not know if I need 75 separate models.